# Delete item in React

Tags: reactjs

Hey I have a problem with remove element in react. After click on delete button I have error in console : 'script.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined at Object.remove at onClick at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback at executeDispatch at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder at executeDispatchesAndRelease at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel at Array.forEach  at forEachAccumulated  at Object.processEventQueue'.

```
        var Movie = React.createClass({
      propTypes: {
        movie: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        remove: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
          React.createElement('li', {key: this.props.movie.id},
            React.createElement(Remove,{remove: this.props.remove, id: this.props.movie.id}),
          )
        )
      }
    });
var MovieElem = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    movies: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        movies
    };
  },

  deleteMovie: function(id) {
    this.setState({
      movies: this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.id !== id)
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('div', {},
        React.createElement('ul', {},
          this.state.movies.map(function(movie) {
            return React.createElement(Movie, {key: movie.id, movie: movie, remove: () => this.deleteMovie.bind(this)});
          })
      )
    )
  }
});

var Remove = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    remove: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('button', {onClick: () => { this.props.remove(this.props.id) }}, 'Delete')
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the map function in order to refer to the `this` value correctly inside of it

```
render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('div', {},
        React.createElement('ul', {},
          this.state.movies.map(function(movie) {
            return React.createElement(Movie, {key: movie.id, movie: movie, remove: this.deleteMovie});
          }.bind(this))
      )
    )
  }
```

Comment: after adding this i have error in console : Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See undefined

Comment: `remove: this.deleteMovie` is what you need after making the change

Comment: Glad to have helped